# Check if an array is an element of another array python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a python array of 3d points such as [p1,p2,...,pn]  where p1 = [x1,y1,zi] I want to check weather a particular point p_i is a member of this, what is the right method for this?

Here is the code which I tried

```
import numpy
my_list = []
for x in range(0,10):
    for y in range(0,10):
        for z  in range(0,5):
            p1 = numpy.array([x,y,z])
            my_list.append(p1)

check_list = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[20,0,20],[5,5,5]])
for p in check_list :
    if p not in my_list:
        print (p)
```

However I;m getting the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Apparently this method works for strings and numbers but not for arrays. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy

my_list = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):
        for z in range(0, 5):
            p1 = numpy.array([x, y, z])
            my_list.append(p1)

check_list = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [20, 0, 20], [5, 5, 5]])
for p in check_list:
    if not numpy.any(numpy.all(p == my_list, axis=1)):
        print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `all` along axis=1 and check if `any` of the result is `True`:

```
for p in check_list:
    if not (p==my_list).all(1).any():
        print(p)
```

Output:

```
[20  0 20]
[5 5 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the below a try

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int


points: List[Point] = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):
        for z in range(0, 5):
            points.append(Point(x, y, z))
print(Point(1, 2, 3) in points)
print(Point(1, 2, 3888) in points)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can you please tell me what exactly this one is doing?                                   .                                                                                                                                            `points: List[Point] = []`  ?

Comment: @brownfox I can tell you for sure :-). `List[Point]` is type hint. It increase the readability of the code and is used by type checkers. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html BTW - I think this solution is cleaner - it does not require any external lib!